# make adding comments/reply links visible

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I am a new user of stack overflow.  I would like to reply to people, but I have no way to.  the links just aren't there.  so I am stuck.  and there's nothing in the FAQ about this either.

make the links obvious they they are a comment or a reply link.  I just can't find it.  is it some sort of hidden hotkey?  humans need to be able to use this.